# JavaScript Filter array of objects based on property of another array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have 2 `array of objects`

```
Tasks
[{
 name: "test",
 type: "one"
},
{
 name: "test2",
 type: 'two'
}]
```

activities

```
[{
 name: "test",
 type: "one"
},
{
 name: "test2",
 type: 'two'
},
{
 name: "test3",
 type: "three"
 }]
```

How can I filter the activities array by properties of the tasks array? I would like this outcome.

activities

```
[{
 name: "test",
 type: "one"
},
{
 name: "test2",
 type: 'two'
}]
```

I have tried using .filter(), but that returns an empty collection.

`let tests = activities.filter(x => tasks.includes(x.type));`

How can I achieve that in Javascript?

Comment: "How can I filter the activities array to only have the objects inside of the tasks array" doesn't that mean you need only tasks array?

Comment: @mehulmpt No I need to filter it by a `property. Let me update that last sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`filter` is the right tool, but `includes` is not. The entries in `tasks` are objects, not strings; none of them will match any of the types in `tests`.

Instead, the simple version uses [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to see if any entries in `tasks` match the type of the activity being tested:

```
let tests = activities.filter(a => tasks.some(t => t.type == a.type));
```

Live Example:

```js
const tasks = [
  {
    name: "test",
    type: "one"
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    type: 'two'
  }
];
const activities = [
  {
    name: "test",
    type: "one"
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    type: 'two'
  },
  {
    name: "test3",
    type: "three"
  }
];
 
let tests = activities.filter(a => tasks.some(t => t.type == a.type));
console.log(tests);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Naturally, that means at least partially re-traversing `tasks` for each entry in `activities`. For the examples you've shown, that's absolutely fine; if `tasks` is hundreds of thousands of entries long or this is done in a tight loop, not so much. :-)

In that situation, you could give yourself a set of known types from `tasks` in advance, then just test against the set:

```
const knownTypes = new Set();
for (const task of tasks) {
    knownTypes.add(task.type);
}
let tests = activities.filter(a => knownTypes.has(a.type));
```

Live Example:

```js
const tasks = [
  {
    name: "test",
    type: "one"
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    type: 'two'
  }
];
const activities = [
  {
    name: "test",
    type: "one"
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    type: 'two'
  },
  {
    name: "test3",
    type: "three"
  }
];
 
const knownTypes = new Set();
for (const task of tasks) {
    knownTypes.add(task.type);
}
let tests = activities.filter(a => knownTypes.has(a.type));
console.log(tests);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Alternately, instead of `Set` you could also use an object for `knownTypes`, creating it via `Object.create(null)` on the off-chance any of your types happens to be something with the same name as a property on `Object.prototype`:

```
const knownTypes = Object.create(null);
for (const task of tasks) {
    knownTypes[task.type] = true;
}
let tests = activities.filter(a => knownTypes[a.type]);
```

Live Example:

```js
const tasks = [
  {
    name: "test",
    type: "one"
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    type: 'two'
  }
];
const activities = [
  {
    name: "test",
    type: "one"
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    type: 'two'
  },
  {
    name: "test3",
    type: "three"
  }
];
 
const knownTypes = Object.create(null);
for (const task of tasks) {
    knownTypes[task.type] = true;
}
let tests = activities.filter(a => knownTypes[a.type]);
console.log(tests);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Almost there. Try using the `.some` array method to check if the item is present, since `includes` won't work for a nested property.

```js
const tasks = [{
 name: "test",
 type: "one"
},
{
 name: "test2",
 type: 'two'
}]

const activities = [{
 name: "test",
 type: "one"
},
{
 name: "test2",
 type: 'two'
},
{
 name: "test3",
 type: "three"
 }]
 
let tests = activities.filter(x => tasks.some(t => t.type === x.type));
console.log(tests)
```