# How to compare two arrays of objects with a filter and save wanted data?

Tags: javascript, arrays

First off, I have to apologize, I'm not entirely certain what to put as the question title so feel free to change it if you have a better idea.

I have two arrays that contain data in the following formats (note that I am only mentioning data pertaining to the issue):

```
1. objects:
   - client:
      - id
      ...
   - partner_code
   ...

2. webusers:
   - client_id
   - partner_code
   ...
```

Now, there may be multiple `webusers` objects in the array with the same `client_id` that may have different `partner_code` values. What I want to achieve is adding only the appropriate `partner_code` to each `objects` entry.

The `objects` array does ***not*** have the `partner_code` field filled with data yet, that is what I'm trying to achieve.

If the case was that the `webusers` array had 3 objects with the same `client_id` but the `partner_code` is different for each object (one of them being 'rtm', second one 'rtm', and the last one 'team1'), I only want to store the 'team1' value in the database under `partner_code` for
all objects with the same `client.id`, if the case was there was only 1 object in the `webusers` array with a certain `client_id`, then that `partner_code` would get stored in the database under `partner_code` for all `objects` with the same `client.id`.

Everything that I attempted had a lot of `forEach()` loops and many failed attempts at using the `filter()` and `find()` array methods which led me to a lot of performance issues since these are pretty big arrays and it never solved my original problem either.

I am honestly lost after many hours of Googling and trying to make this work over multiple months (this is a pretty important function for the web app that I'm building but I've been delaying it as much as I could to try everything I could think of).

Comment: i think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066465/javascript-filter-array-of-objects-based-on-property-of-another-array-of-objects)  can help you

Comment: @mahmoudettouahri Thanks for all the help and pointers, I've updated the question, having a hard time phrasing all of this properly so it makes sense.

Comment: @TonyM. sorry but it still not clear to me ... you have 2 types of objects the first is client that have an id and you need to add a partnercode to it. the second is webuser that have a client id and partner code . there can be multiple webusers with the same clientid but different partner codes . now it seems you want to filter ther webusers based on partnercode ... now i want to ask whatis an accepted partnercode and what is not accepted . in your example you are saying team1 is accepted but rtm is skipped

Comment: @mahmoudettouahri I'll edit the whole question in a bit here and add more examples, sorry, I posted the question pretty late so things just don't make sense the way they should.